# many to many relationship mysql design

Tags: mysql, sql, database

many user can have many tab so I designed this table

```
user
uId (PK)



user-tab
uId (FK)
tabId (FK)



tab
tabId (PK)
```

but when I try to add `FK` in `user-tab` I got this error

```
1050 - Table '.\db\tab@002duser' already exists
```

Comment: How are you adding the FK?  Possible conflict with the name of the FK/Index?

Comment: @Devon yes, I go into user-tab table and click on relation-view in myphpadmin

Comment: Show us a `DESCRIBE table` pls

Comment: @pc-shooter what does that mean?

Comment: Mysql error messages are sometimes a little bit missleading. If I recall right this error could appear if you choose an alreay used FK name.

Comment: @pc-shooter tq, it was the - name issue..

Comment: Edit your title to summarize your specific technical issue. How is your Question different from all the other Questions asking about many-to-many relationships in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem of your DB-Design or existing records, but a naming problem.

MySQL rules for naming unquoted identifiers are  **`snake_case_writing`** instead of `CamelCase` or `dash-style-writing`, use

From the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers (not strings, values):
>
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

**Edit**

Another abridgment from the docs (*This and more to read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/naming-conventions.html)*)

> Naming Conventions For identifiers formed from multiple words,
> separate each component with underscore rather than capitalization.
> Thus, use my_var instead of myVar or MyVar.
>
> Avoid capitalization except for class names; class names should begin
> with a capital letter.
>
> class Item; class Query_arena; class Log_event; Avoid function names,
> structure elements, or variables that begin or end with '_'.
>
> Use long function and variable names in English. This will make your
> code easier to read for all developers.