# MySQL - case sensitive view name

Tags: mysql

I have problem with case sensitive VIEW names. 
In my.ini file I have line

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

Table names OK. But name of new created views are convert to lower case. View definition is also converted to lower case.
Ex.:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_TestView
AS
SELECT Id FROM tblTable1
```

Result name: `vw_testview`
Definition: `SELECT 'Id' FROM tbltable1`

How can I change this behavior? Thanks for help!

Comment: There are very good reasons why one should _not_ use uppercase characters in table names. This can cause severe problems with portability of code. Only use lowercase characters for table and view names.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260824/many-to-many-relationship-mysql-design/23261437#23261437

Comment: @pc-shooter Thanks, but how can I use this tip to get what I want? Please for wider explanation

Comment: Just don't use uppecase letters for your viewnames, use snake_case

Comment: I know your point. But requirements of my client DB structur forcing me to use it. I know that is possible to force MySQL to accept naming like in my example (I was working with that config on some public hostings), but I don't know how to do it in my local environment :(