# Keep MySQL Database View Capital letter After restore DB

Tags: mysql

After restore MySQL Database, I can keep all the tables with Capital letter name.
But views' name are changed to small letter.

Can i change some setting to make views keep Capital letter name after restored DB?

P.S. I can change view to Capital letter name again after restore, but i don't want to do it everytime.

Comment: are you looking like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lcase?

Comment: no, I want to keep the view name with Capital letter after restored database. But still thank a lot.

Comment: can you explain with code or query ?

Comment: View names are converted to lower case when you create the view. I don't think it's possible to change that.

Comment: See http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,520736

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263698/mysql-case-sensitive-view-name

Answer (score 0):

[Example Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC4uK.jpg)

I can create and change view name to Capital letter.
But after reconnect Workbench or restore DB,
They chnaged to small letter.

It seem to be the small letter view name is the rule,
Thank you for everyone answer my stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the value of *lower_case_table_names* in your mysql.cnf config file is the same in both the source db and the db where you restore the data

check out the possible values for *lower_case_table_names* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names